# string less or equal datetime django

Tags: django, string, datetime, equals

I need return all objects with date is less or equal 2014-12-29. I have uma string "2014-12-29"
If I want get date equal or less the 2014-12-29, I use:

`Attendance.objects.filter(start_date__lte="2014-12-29")`

But start_date is a datetime.
How do I get objects with date is "2014-12-29 23:59:59"?

Using only "2014-12-29" django complete this string with "0:00:00"?
thereby: "2014-12-29 00:00:00"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try with [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strptime) of time [time module](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#module-time)

```
check_date = time.strptime('2014-12-29 23:59:59', "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")

Attendance.objects.filter(start_date__lte=check_date)
```